# Why aren't dust devils extremely unstable?

Tags: wind, tornado

Based on my intuition, I would expect a dust devil to rapidly entrain slow-moving air and stop spinning.

My logic goes something like this:

- The dust devil is made of air that is warmer than the surroundings.
- Therefore the base of the dust devil will have lower pressure.
- Friction with the ground prevents gradient wind balance.
- So environmental air is sucked in and mixes with the air in the dust  devil, slowing down the dust devil’s rotation.

Why doesn't this happen?  [Dust devils typically last minutes, but can even last hours at times.](https://www.weather.gov/fgz/DustDevil#:%7E:text=In%20most%20locations%2C%20dust%20devils,reach%2060%20mph%20or%20greater.)

Comment: a weather event that only last for a few minutes is unstable.